# set @media with Or Conditions

Tags: html, css

I have to apply a same style for viewports smallers than 1024 and bigger than 1920, I think that something like this should be posible:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) or (min-width: 1920px)  {
    ...CSS Code
}
```

However it does not work, I do not want to repeat all css code twice for each size, neither I can import from html the same file from both medias (Since I only can have a minified css).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want a style to apply to screens smaller than 768px AND larger than 1920px wide? This is a non-issue if you don't have a use-case for it.

Comment: @TylerH Use your imagination. Or was added to the spec because people wanted it.

Comment: @bjb568 said people provided use cases